# How to save a custom model with custom layer Tensorflow2

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, model

I am trying to save weight of model: `model.save_weights('filepath')`

My model is

```py
class CLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, hidden_units=[]):
        super(PartCoder, self).__init__()
        # self.layers = NoDependency([])
        # self.__dict__['layers'] = []
        self.layers = []
        for u in hidden_units:
            self.layers.append(keras.layers.Dense(u))

class CModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, hidden_units):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()
        self.cLayers = CLayer(hidden_units=hidden_units)


model_1 = CModel(hidden_units=[2,4])  
model_1.save_weights("filepath_1")  #--> worked

model_2 = CModel(hidden_units=[2,4])
model_2.load_weights("filepaht_1")  #--> worked

#train model_2
model_2.save_weights("filepath_2") #--> Crash here
```

Result:

```
Epoch 5: Loss = 72.76963806152344
Epoch 10: Loss = 68.98507690429688
Epoch 15: Loss = 65.25872039794922
Epoch 20: Loss = 61.60311508178711
Epoch 25: Loss = 58.087005615234375
```

But with errors:

```
ValueError: Unable to save the object ListWrapper([<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f032829d4e0>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f032829da90>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f032ad38e80>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f0328165048>]) (a list wrapper constructed to track trackable TensorFlow objects). A list element was replaced (__setitem__, __setslice__), deleted (__delitem__, __delslice__), or moved (sort). In order to support restoration on object creation, tracking is exclusively for append-only data structures.

If you don't need this list checkpointed, wrap it in a tf.contrib.checkpoint.NoDependency object; it will be automatically un-wrapped and subsequently ignored.
```

After I find on google, I tried to use:

```
self.__dict__['layers'] = []
#OR: self.layers = NoDependency([])
```

for saving list of layer in `CLayer` class. This solution is works **but** the weights in layer is not updated.

```
Epoch 5: Loss = 76.57701873779297
Epoch 10: Loss = 76.57701873779297
Epoch 15: Loss = 76.57701873779297
Epoch 20: Loss = 76.57701873779297
```

Link: [Tried solution](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36916)

My question is how to save the model with custom layers as the above example model without error.

Answer (score -1):

After long time I search and fix in all way that I can. Then I have moved to Pytorch. It is easier to saving model without error.
Finally, I solved by using Pytorch and it worked.